# Struts logic iterate tag to loop through table rows

Tags: loops, html-table, struts-1

I am using struts. How can I use an iterate tag to create a table row that iterates through first name and last name when each iterate is using a different list?

```
 <logic:iterate name="fName" id="listMsgId1">
      <tr>
           <td>First Name: <bean:write name="listMsgId1"/></td>
           <logic:iterate name="lName" id="listMsgId2" >
           <td>Last Name: <bean:write name="listMsgId2"/></td>     
           </logic:iterate>     
      </tr>
 </logic:iterate>
```

Currently the output that I am getting is first name: juan last name: brown last name: smith
first name: ken last name: brown last name: smith

I would like the last name to only appear once for each first name and not for as many rows that are created.

Answer (score 1):

Create a proper data structure in the action and pass that instead of two lists.

Answer (score 1):

@Dave answer is correct though this is something you may find helpful,

You should create `ActioForm` containing 2 properties.

```
public class PersonDetail extends ActionForm 
{
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;

public void setFirstName(String newFirstName) {
    firstName = newFirstName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String newLastName) {
    lastName = newLastName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
}
```

Now iterate as per requirement, Assuming `PersonDetail` is `ArrayList` in your action class.

```
<logic:iterate name="PersonDetail" id="listUsers">
     <tr>
          <td>First Name: <bean:write name="listUsers" property="FirstName"/></td>
          <td>Last Name: <bean:write name="listUsers" property="LastName"/></td>
     <tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note you can do it with hashmap easily.
In java class you will create a hashap, code will be something like that

```
HashMap<String,String> myMap = new HashMap();
myMap.put("DummyFirstName", "DummyLastName");
myMap.put("raheel","arif");
myMap.put("dave","newton");
request.setAttribute("SubscribedLists", myMap);
```

and jsp page code will be

```
               <logic:iterate name="SubscribedLists" id="SubscribedListsId">

                        <div>                         
                        <p><bean:write name="SubscribedListsId" property="key"/></p>                             
                        </div>

                        <div>
                          <p><bean:write name="SubscribedListsId" property="value"/></p>
                        </div>
                </logic:iterate>
```

In my example I used divs you can easily convert it into table for your code